# Is Ciao Bella's "Rosemary and Olive Oil Gelato" savory?

Tags: sugar, ice-cream, olive-oil, cookbook

I am about to make ice cream (for dessert) from *The Ciao Bella book for Gelato and Sorbetto* and was thinking about trying the *Rosemary and Olive Oil Gelato*. It says something about being savory, but it has the same amount of sugar as most of the other gelatos there. I have tried (sweet) olive oil gelato elsewhere, and it was very good (though unusual).

**Is this Gelato fit (as an ice cream) for a normal dessert? Is it eaten as if it is sweet?**

Edit: Does "savory", in this case, mean it's not sweet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can be both savory and sweet; that is the point of that gelato.

It is one of those dessert component that needs to be served with something else to balance it out.

I'd serve it with a lemon biscotti or a lemon pound cake.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering about that (first part). It's just that normally, when I hear savory ice cream, I think of something that has no sugar (like cheddar or crab gelato).

Comment: Also, what's stupid is that I need 15 reputation to upvote answers *to my own question*

Comment: Problem solved it looks like @bob.

Comment: @bob welcome to our site! You are not the first one to stumble over that rule. We do have a whole "parallel" site called Meta, with questions and answers about how the system behaves, and feature requests, and somebody has asked for a change there. You can read the conversation here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661. Also, I am writing this 14 hours after you posted your quesiton, and you already have more than 15 reputation, just from that one question you asked, so it's not a high bar.